# mariadb Error Reading Communication Packets

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mariadb, rancher

I have a problem. When I split my MariaDB from main server to another server (my database server is running MariaDB docker from latest tag) I got an error:

> Got an error writing communication packets

i have 2 server the one is a webserver (no db) the other is a ubuntu 20.04 with 4gig ram and 4 core(2gh per core)

The port is open and my PING is less than 1ms.

I tried with a basic WP site DB and the connection is OK, there was no problem, but my database is about 1GB and I guess this made this problem.

I also try to connect over private network (`192.168.100.25`) instead of public IP, but the problem is same.

Here is my MariaDB log

> Aborted connection 3 to db: 'wpdb' user: 'root' host: 'myip' (Got an error reading communication packets)

> Aborted connection 5 to db: 'wpdb' user: 'root' host: 'myip' (Got an error writing communication packets)

I also edited MariaDB config:

- increased max_allowed_packet to 1GB
- increased net_buffer_length to 1000000

but nothing changes!

here is mariadb variable :
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/yHFRh7CnVC/

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS:
https://pastebin.pl/view/b3db2b91

show process list:

8,root,31.56.66.249:60612,,Query,0,starting,SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST,0

ulimit on server root:

```
ubuntu@rangoabzar:~$ ulimit -a 
ulimit -a 
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15608
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15608
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

ulimit in docker container:

```
root@63aa95764534:/#  ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15608
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

[iostat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmPxO.png)

[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Zoq.png)

Comment: How did you sp[l]it mariadb into mysql? Why did you change? Did you verify that `max_allowed_packet` reflects this value? Can you show some more context of the mysql log by editing your question.

Comment: @danblack i meant i transfer db from main server to another vps on the same network

Comment: @danblack yes after i set in mariadb config show variables on mysql cli shows it ok here is my mariadb variable log:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/yHFRh7CnVC/

Comment: @danblack also i edited the question i did not change the driver from mariadb to mysql i just transfer to another server

Comment: @danblack only error log on mariadb server is that Got an error writing communication packets i also check it on another vps but still have problem i believe there is sth with my config ( i just install ubuntu and docker and pull mariadb..)

Comment: Try increasing the [max_connection_errors](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_connect_errors) to maximum to ensure that any transient errors aren't causing the host to back blacklisted.

Comment: @danblack did it nothing changed

Comment: @danblack i also show additional info at the question

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error by doing a query that returned multiple rows, then processing those rows using rows.Next() (in Golang), and exiting early because of an unrelated error without calling rows.Close(). The confusing part was that it worked the first few times, but eventually failed, indicating some resource (connections?) was being used up.

I was able to take advantage of Golang's defer statement, and just do

defer rows.Close()

before ever calling rows.Next(), but calling rows.Close() before every early exit from the rows.Next() loop works as well.